# How can I pass a variable when calling a route?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, routes, vuetify.js

I want to display the customer's name in a new vue page(from Messages.vue to CustomerMessages.vue). I don't know how to pass this variable into the child vue.

I have tried props but it doesn't work as I expected.

```
{ path: '/messages/:id/customers', component: CustomerMessages, name: 'CustomerMessage', beforeEnter: requireAuth }
```

---

```
this.$router.push({ name: 'CustomerMessage', params: { id: item.ID }, data: {name: this.customers.FullName} })
```

---

```
{{name}}

props:{
name: ''
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue-router doesn't let you pass arbitrary data to routes like that.

If you want a parent component to share some data with a child route, then you can just bind it on the `<router-view>` component like you would with any other component prop.

**Parent**

```vue
<router-view :name="name"></router-view>
```

```js
data() {
  return {
    name: 'Alice'
  }
}
```

**Child**

```vue
{{ name }}
```

```js
props: ['name']
```